# Caffe execution

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I am starting to use `caffe` for deep learning. I have the `.caffemodel` file with my trained weights and a particular neural network. I am using python interface.

I've seen that I can load my network and my weights by doing this:

```
solver=caffe.get_solver('prototxtfile.prototxt')
solver.net.copy_from('weights.caffemodel')
```

But I do not want to fine-tuned my application. I just want to use those weights. I want to execute the network and for each image from the Imagenet data set I want to obtain the result of the classification (not the accuracy of an entire batch). How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: firstly load your network and the source network and then assign the source weights to your network and save your modified network (do sth like [surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) example ,then simply load your input to net and forward  network (`net.forward`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand the attached lines of python code and adjust them to your needs. It's not my code but I wrote a similar piece to test my models.
The source is:
https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~zk15/deep_learning/classify_test.py

If you don't want to fine-tune a pre-trained model, it's obvious that you don't need a solver. The solver is what optimizes the model. If you want to predict the class probability for an image, you actually just have to do a forward pass. Keep in mind that your deploy.prototxt must have a proper last layer which uses either a softmax or sigmoid function (depending on the architecture). You can't use the loss function from the train_val.prototxt for this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make sure that caffe is on the python path:
caffe_root = '../'  # this file is expected to be in {caffe_root}/examples
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')

import caffe

# Set the right path to your model definition file, pretrained model weights,
# and the image you would like to classify.
MODEL_FILE = '../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = '../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'
IMAGE_FILE = 'images/cat.jpg'

caffe.set_mode_cpu()
net = caffe.Classifier(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED,
                       mean=np.load(caffe_root + 'python/caffe/imagenet/ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy').mean(1).mean(1),
                       channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                       raw_scale=255,
                       image_dims=(256, 256))
input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)
plt.imshow(input_image)

prediction = net.predict([input_image])  # predict takes any number of images, and formats them for the Caffe net automatically
print 'prediction shape:', prediction[0].shape
plt.plot(prediction[0])
print 'predicted class:', prediction[0].argmax()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. WHat happens with the image dimensions? In that code the param image_dims is 256x256, what happens if the image does not fit the code?

Comment: You simply resize them using a package called SciImage. Don't use caffe's operations for that. You can also change the input dimensions, just make sure that your model was trained for your dimensions and resize them before passing to the net.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: He/she could use Caffe operations for resizing. In fact, Caffe has a bunch of useful pre-processing operations that can be applied to input data (see [Transformer class](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/kVDppVZo3jQ)). And when you say SciImage, do you mean scikit-image?

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use when I need to forward an image through my network:

```
import caffe

caffe.set_mode_cpu()             #If you are using CPU
#caffe.set_mode_gpu()            #or if you are using GPU

model_def = "path/to/deploy.prototxt"         #architecture
model_weights = "path/to/weights.caffemodel"  #weights

net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights,
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)


#Let's forward a single image (let's say inputImg)
#'data' is the name of my input blob
net.blobs["data"].data[0] = inputImg
out = net.forward()

# to get the final softmax probability
# in my case, 'prob' is the name of our last blob
# a softmax layer that will output the score/probability for our problem
outputScore = net.blobs["prob"].data[0]   #[0] here because we forwarded a single image
```

In this example, the `inputImg` dimensions must match the dimensions of the images used during training, as well as all preprocessing done.